# Android Firebase email address is badly formatted

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-authentication

i want to save signup details through firebase realtime database but when i click on signup button the error appears that the email is badly formatted. I already connected my project with firebase and included all the dependencies. i enter email in correct order like someone@gmail.com but still it give error. Here is the code.

java

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySignupBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        binding.signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = binding.signupEmail.getEditText().toString(), password = binding.signupPassword.getEditText().toString();
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     if (task.isSuccessful()){
                         User user = new User(binding.signupName.getEditText().toString(),
                                 binding.signupProfession.getEditText().toString(),
                                 binding.signupEmail.getEditText().toString().trim(),
                                 binding.signupPassword.getEditText().toString().trim());

                         String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid(); // this will get the id of newly registered user

                         database.getReference().child("Users").child(id).setValue(user);

                         Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "User Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                     else {
                         Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        binding.signupLoginTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/signup_name"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:hint="Name"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/black"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup_profession"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_name"
    app:startIconTint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
       />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/signup_profession"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:hint="Profession"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/black"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup_email"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signup_name"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signup_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signup_name"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_profession"
    app:startIconTint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/signup_email"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:hint="Email"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/black"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup_password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signup_profession"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signup_profession"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signup_profession"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"
    app:startIconTint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/signup_password"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconTint="@color/black"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup_btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/signup_email"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/signup_email"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signup_email"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_password"
    app:startIconTint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're calling `toString` on the `EditText` object, which doesn't give you the value from the text field, but rather gives you a debug view of the field.

To get the **value** of an `EditText`, you'll want to call `getText().toString()` on it

```
                                               // 
String email = binding.signupEmail.getEditText().getText().toString(), 
       password = binding.signupPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
                                                     //
```

To troubleshoot this type of problem. I recommend:

- either setting a breakpoint on the line of code that isn't working (`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` here), running the code in a debugger, and checking the values that you're passing to the API.
- or logging the values that you're passing to the API, and checking what you get in the logcat output.

Comment: thanks for your response but i assigned id to TextInputLayout, therefore getText() is not available. Only i have to select getEditText().

Comment: Did you see the second half of my answer, where I explain how to troubleshoot this type of problem? Did you try it? What did you find out when you did?

Comment: I didn't get your troubleshooting solution. But i assigned id to the EditText field inside TextInputLayout and replaced the getEditText() with getText() and that worked.